# How to rename the data in each row to the unique number in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I rename or label the data with 2 columns that have the same value to the unique number.For example

Here is my sample data:

```
col1   col2
A1     B1
A1     C1
A1     B2
B1     C2
C2     D1
```

Expected:

```
col1   col2  new_col1  new_col2
    A1     B1      1         2
    A1     C1      1         3
    A1     B2      1         4
    B1     C2      2         5
    C2     D1      5         6
```

Any guidelines for this situation? I'm thinking about the `np.random` but it only can define only one column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) with reshaped DataFrame to `MultiIndex Series` by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
s = df.stack()
df = df.join(pd.Series(pd.factorize(s)[0] + 1, index=s.index).unstack().add_prefix('new_'))
print (df)
  col1 col2  new_col1  new_col2
0   A1   B1         1         2
1   A1   C1         1         3
2   A1   B2         1         4
3   B1   C2         2         5
4   C2   D1         5         6
```

Comment: i have sattled! it's my mistake that i input the wrong parameter. thank you for your help